# how to get label and ID information from below HTML using python beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I extracted ID and Label(10870,7th Phase JP Nagar) from below HTML code

```html
<input id="filter_data" type="hidden" value="{&quot;Locality&quot;
:{&quot;Top_Results_Array&quot;
:{&quot;0&quot;
:{&quot;ID&quot;:&quot;10870&quot;,&quot;LABEL&quot;:&quot;7th Phase JP Nagar&quot;,&quot;SELECTED&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;COUNT&quot;:202.0},&quot;1&quot;
:{&quot;ID&quot;:&quot;2259&quot;,&quot;LABEL&quot;:&quot;Electronic City&quot;,&quot;SELECTED&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;COUNT&quot;:126.0},&quot;2&quot;
:{&quot;ID&quot;:&quot;2265&quot;,&quot;LABEL&quot;:&quot;Koramangala&quot;,&quot;SELECTED&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;COUNT&quot;:118.0},&quot;3&quot;
:{&quot;ID&quot;:&quot;11646&quot;,&quot;LABEL&quot;:&quot;BTM 2nd Stage&quot;,&quot;SELECTED&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;COUNT&quot;:118.0}},&quot;More_Locality_Array&quot;
:{&quot;0&quot;
:{&quot;ID&quot;:&quot;2277&quot;,&quot;LABEL&quot;:&quot;Bellandur&quot;,&quot;SELECTED&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;COUNT&quot;:102.0},&quot;1&quot;
:{&quot;ID&quot;:&quot;5467&quot;,&quot;LABEL&quot;:&quot;Hulimavu&quot;,&quot;SELECTED&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;COUNT&quot;:95.0},&quot;2&quot;
:{&quot;ID&quot;:&quot;2261&quot;,&quot;LABEL&quot;:&quot;HSR Layout&quot;,&quot;SELECTED&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;COUNT&quot;:94.0},&quot;3&quot;:
:{&quot;ID&quot;:&quot;2293&quot;,&quot;LABEL&quot;:&quot;Jigani&quot;,&quot;SELECTED&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;COUNT&quot;:91.0},&quot;4&quot;
:{&quot;ID&quot;:&quot;2249&quot;,&quot;LABEL&quot;:&quot;Bannerghatta Road&quot;,&quot;SELECTED&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;COUNT&quot;:83.0},&quot;5&quot;
:{&quot;ID&quot;:&quot;2264&quot;,&quot;LABEL&quot;:&quot;Kanakpura Road&quot;,&quot;SELECTED&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;COUNT&quot;:83.0},&quot;6&quot;:
```

I have tried following python code which just get the value of input(id=filter_data)

```
for loc in soup.find_all('input',id='filter_data'):
print(loc.get('value'))
```

i am getting below output

```html
{"Locality":{"Top_Results_Array":{
"0":{"ID":"10870","Locality":"7th Phase JP Nagar","SELECTED":"","COUNT":202.0}
,"1":{"ID":"2259","LABEL":"Electronic City","SELECTED":"","COUNT":126.0}
,"2":{"ID":"2265","LABEL":"Koramangala","SELECTED":"","COUNT":118.0}
,"3":{"ID":"11646","LABEL":"BTM 2nd Stage","SELECTED":"","COUNT":118.0}}
,"More_Locality_Array":{"0":{
"ID":"2277","LABEL":"Bellandur","SELECTED":"","COUNT":102.0}
,"1":{"ID":"5467","LABEL":"Hulimavu","SELECTED":"","COUNT":95.0}
,"2":{"ID":"2261","LABEL":"HSR Layout","SELECTED":"","COUNT":94.0}
,"3":{"ID":"2293","LABEL":"Jigani","SELECTED":"","COUNT":91.0}
,"4":{"ID":"2249","LABEL":"Bannerghatta Road","SELECTED":"","COUNT":83.0}
,"5":{"ID":"2264","LABEL":"Kanakpura Road","SELECTED":"","COUNT":83.0}
```

but i need below output

10870 7th Phase JP Nagar

2259 Electronic City

2265 Koramangala

11646 BTM 2nd Stage

2277 Bellandur

5467 Hulimavu

2261 HSR Layout

.
.

Could you please help me on this

Comment: can you share link of webpage ?

Comment: I am trying to get all localities(Top Localities and More localities)

Comment: okay let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can suggest is to `jsonify` your result set and extract information as you want. Problem was the output format of `unicode`. You may experiment with this code after getting `result`, you can get data in your own fashion. You may load data as list, dict etc and get values as you like.

```
import json
exp = soup.find_all('input', attrs={"id":"filter_data"})
abc = exp[0].get('value') # len(exp) = 1 
abc = abc.decode('utf-8')  # since its unicode
result = json.loads(abc)
result
```

If you want to see result values having location, check

```
print result.values()[2]
```

In dictionary see and decide what all you want to get.

```
dict(result)
```

Play around with the json, you will get what you want. I hope this help.